# Dynamic composite key in Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework

I have a database where the convention is that tables contain historic records, numerated incrementally. For example a Product with `Id` 17 might have three records in the `[Products]` table:

```
Id  Version  Name
--  -------  ----
17  1        <null>
17  2        'Pinpogn Ball'
17  3        'Pingpong ball`
```

The most up-to-date record is the one with `Id` 17 and `Version` 3.

Furthermore, the convention in this database is that records that reference such Products, specify only the `Product Id`, taking for granted that it's the record with `MAX(Version)` that is being referred to.

For example, the [ProductColors] table might have a record:

```
Id  Version  ProductId  Color
--  -------  ---------  -----
99  1        17         'Fluorescent Green'
```

My challenge: I am trying to access this DB using Entity Framework 6 Code First. Is there a way for me to adapt EF6 to the conventions in the DB?

That is, can I "teach" EF to de-reference columns like the above `ProductID` column using the record having the correct `Id` and the highest `Version`?

Comment: I would use a partial classe, write my own code in a property, and use it like all other property of the PorductColors entity. But i don't think this is what you are looking for

Comment: I think doing this the "proper" Entity Framework way would involve writing a new managed provider that automatically adds the code to get the latest version.  You could also try pulling from views that only contain the latest version of each record.

Comment: Thanks. Any links for how to write said managed provider?